# Finding if a string contains any string in a collection

Tags: java, string, data-structures, collections

I'm trying to improve the performance of a Java-function I have that is determining whether a given search string contains >0 of the strings in a collection. This could look like premature optimization but the function is called A LOT so any speed up would be very beneficial.

The code currently looks like this:

```
public static boolean containsAny(String searchString, List<String> searchCollection) {
    int size = searchCollection.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String stringInCollection = searchCollection.get(i);
        if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(stringInCollection)) {
            // This is a performance optimization of contains.
            if (searchString.indexOf(stringInCollection, 0) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The list typically has about 30 elements and the same collection is reused a lot between each call.

The code above is a pretty straightforward linear search. I don't think it can be significantly improved unless we change the data structure to make it better than O(n). Are there any data structures that would enable me to do that?

Comment: @keyser how would sorting the list help? It's checking if any of the strings contains the search string. Just because a string doesn't start with the search string doesn't imply that it doesn't contain the search string.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that he/she meant substring :p

Comment: Choose another data structure to store your strings. For example, a `Map<Character, List<String>>` where the key is a letter for the abecedarium and the `List<String>` contains a sorted list of the words that starts with the character used as key. Or use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: I like the idea of using Map<Character, List<String>> to map characters to the subset of strings having that character! I don't really see how trie would help though. Aren't trie just for prefix searches?

Comment: They're mainly used for that, yes. Im not sure about their applicability. This made me think of the [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) which can be solved efficiently with suffix trees. It's not spot on, but could be used.

Comment: How big are your strings?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis typically between 10 and 40 characters.

Comment: @Yrlec That sounds like a decent length for a Trie.

Comment: Guys, I've just edited the question. I formulated it incorrectly. The code is checking whether the search string contains any of the string in the collection. Not whether any string in the collection contains the search string. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: How long is `searchString`?

Comment: Check out [Aho Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). You have to construct a state machine, but after that, search is fast.

Comment: @arshajii about 100 characters.

Comment: Is the list constant in any way? If so you could consider viewing it as one big array of chars and strip that array of recurring sequences (for faster searching).

Comment: You have not specified your particular problem, but you could get away with re-arranging your list depending on how often a string is encountered. If you are parsing natural language, you would expect words like "you", "or", "and" to be found pretty often, so your early return from the method might be of some use. But then again, it depends on what you need it for..

Comment: Yeah, the list can be considered constant. It's sometimes reconstructed but it's so rare that the reconstruction time can be approximated to 0.

Comment: @Daniel it's handling file system paths. It's basically a blacklist that tries to determine whether a certain path contains any of the blacklisted strings.

Comment: @Yrlec does each string in the backlist need to match a part in the path fully, or partial matching must be considered too?

Comment: I've done some perf mesaurements of the current suggestions, and your current code is showing much better performance than the one proposed by me, and even better than the one by @Joop based on regex pattern (even if the pattern is cached).

Comment: The perf test gist: https://gist.github.com/vlad-at-yteq/f3680dc2b07bb70f205a

Comment: In the performance test gist, the "needles" occur multiple times. Just by using `List<String> uniqueNeedles = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(needles));` it becomes much faster.

Comment: After a quick test with http://ahocorasick.org/ , it **seems** like this does not bring a great (only a small) advantage in this case. Presumably, the strings are too short (and there are too few, too different ones), so that the overhead that is caused by a sophisticated data structure is not compensated by the theoretically smaller asymptotic running time. But again: I think this depends on the number/structure/lengths of the strings, so YMMV.

Comment: By the way Contains calls IndexOf so it doesnt really maky any difference http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

Comment: Beyond what the others have said, instead of using a list, consider storing the strings in a single large string with corresponding arrays of integers for the individual string offsets and lengths. That should avoid the cpu having to go off to different areas of memory to fetch each string and allow it to make better use of its caches. Secondly may be do some gross filtering first, eg compare the hash codes of the strings and only bother to compare the strings themselves if the hash codes match.

Comment: You'd want to modify the ahocorasick.org implementation to better fit your use-case.  ahocorasick.org finds all the matches, you can stop at the first match.  That is a significant difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible to speed it up significantly with Aho-Corasick algorithm.

You can build an Aho-Corasick automaton for a collection using O(total length of all strings in a collections) time and space. Then it will be possible to check if one of the strings in a collection is a substring of a given string S in O(S.length) time by traversing this automaton.

Answer (score 9):

```
// Make a regex pattern (once only):
StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
for (String sought : searchCollection) {
    if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(sought)) {
        if (pattern.length() != 0) {
            pattern.append('|');
        }
        pattern.append(Pattern.quote(sought));
    }
}
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(" + pattern + ")");
```

This creates a pattern of alternatives like `"(abc|def|ghi)"`. You might consider a case-insensitive search.

And in the function `containsAny`:

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(searchString);
return m.find();
```

Regex compilation is relatively smart. It would be comparable to using a search tree of your collection of sought words: `"agent" and "agitator" to ("ag", ("ent", "itator"))`

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and see how it performs.

Comment: But if search string itself contains "|" symbol , then it may leads wrong result.

Comment: @SivaKumar `Pattern.quote(sought)` should return `sought` with all regex special characters escaped.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thx. For example (abc|def|ghi) , I want to search bc| , it will return true. But none of the string contains bc| , now it will become problem.

Comment: @SivaKumar you mean a find on "abc|" (you left out 'a') will yield true as abc was sought. For _entire_ word searches the search string could use a boundary marker: `"\\b(abc|def|ghi)\\b"`.

Comment: If the pattern were `abc|def|ghi`, searching for a literal `bc|` would not return true.  If one of the strings you want to search for did contain a literal pipe character, you'd just have to make the pattern builder a little more sophisticated to escape it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede thanks, so I misunderstood the comment. Forgot to tell that `|` ("or") separates match alternatives.

Comment: I think `Matcher#find()` is also O(n) for the length of the input, which is why I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is a CPU intensive operation and not long running or blocked on I/O.   If you are using Java 8 you can use parallel streams to do processing in parallel as shown below. The method has been changed to use `Collection` instead of `List` to keep it more flexible.

```
public static boolean containsAny(final String searchString,
        final Collection<String> searchCollection) {
    return searchCollection.stream().parallel()
            .anyMatch(x -> searchString.indexOf(x) > -1);
}
```

Furthermore, instead of using `List`, a `Set` should be used as the underlying data structure so that duplicate entries, if any, will be eliminated.

Answer (score 3):

**You can complete your search in approximately 2/3 the time by using the Aho Corasick algorithm.**

The accepted answer from @user2040251 among others (myself included) suggested the Aho Corasick algorithm.

From your comments I can see that you aren't looking for a general solution but a solution that performs well in a particular use-case.

@Vlad created a possible test suite to benchmark some proposed solutions.

Tests performed by @Marco13 of the Java implementation at http://ahocorasick.org/ indicate that your initial implementation was faster.

Your comments have provided significant additional details about the problem you are trying to solve:

- Approximately 30 strings to search for
- The strings to look for are 10 - 40 characters long.
- The string to search in is usually about 100 characters long.
- The string you are searching is a file path.

[I made a couple of quick modifications to @Vlad's gist to better match the specifics of the problem you described.](https://gist.github.com/5d265ac7fa0c17e63fec.git)

I'd previously commented that the Aho-Corasick implementation others had tested was finding all potential matches.  A method that returned once the first match was found should be much faster.
To see if my intuition was correct I [created a branch](https://github.com/rripken/aho-corasick) of [Robert Bor's java Aho-Corasick implementation](http://ahocorasick.org/).
This branch has now been merged into Aho-Corasick!

- Completed 100000 containsAny in 4337 ms (avg 0 ms)
- Completed 100000 containsAnyWithRegex in 41153 ms (avg 0 ms)
- Completed 100000 containsAnyWithOffset in 23624 ms (avg 0 ms)
- Completed 100000 containsAnyAhoCorasickDotOrg in 7956 ms (avg 0 ms)
- Completed 100000 containsAnyAhoCorasickDotOrgMatches in 5351 ms (avg 0 ms)
- **Completed 100000 containsAnyAhoCorasickDYoo in 2948 ms (avg 0 ms)**
- Completed 100000 containsAnyHospool in 7052 ms (avg 0 ms)
- Completed 100000 containsAnyRaita in 5397 ms (avg 0 ms)
- Completed 100000 containsAnyJava8StreamParallel in 8285 ms (avg 0 ms)

I also implemented a method that performed each search in its own thread.   That implementation was horrible and performed approximately 10x slower.

**Update:** Since my initial testing I've come across [An even faster Aho-Corasick implementation.](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/java/index.html)

I included a benchmark on the Java 8 parallel stream implementation suggested by @GladwinB as well as two [com.eaio.stringsearch](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/) implementations.

There may still be gains to be had.  This paper, for example, describes an set matching variation of Aho-Corasick that sounds appropriate for your problem.[Towards Faster String Matching for Intrusion Detection](http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~pld/courses/447/fall05/coit.etal.faster_matching.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the best suited data structure for this is a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). For a string of size `n`, building the tree takes `Theta(n)`, and searching a sub-string of length `m` in it, takes `O(m)`.

This is one of those data structures that are extremely well suited (and intended) for searching strings. It's a very common data structure with many implementations online.

Answer (score 2):

Compare with this a sort of inverted and optimised version:

```
  public static boolean containsAny(String searchString, List<String> searchCollection) {
    for (int offset = 0; offset < searchString.length(); offset++) {
      for (String sought: searchCollection) {
        int remainder = searchString.length() - offset;
        if (remainder >= sought.length && searchString.startsWith(sought, offset)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

*Note the usage of startsWith with offset.*

Answer (score 2):

As many other people have answered, there are better data structures in general for storing and searching strings.  The problem in your case is that your list only has 30 entries.  The overhead added by using a more complex data structure and algorithm could easily outweigh the gain you would get from it.

Don't get me wrong, your bottleneck is the indexOf line. It looks like it accounts for 95% of the processing.  But if other data structures don't help (I tried an off-the-shelf Aho-Corasick Trie and it was twice as slow), here's a something to check...

The comment about using indexOf instead of contains is questionable.  In my tests.  I saw around 1.5 million lookups per second with "contains" and only about 700K with indexOf.  If you have the same results, that will double your speed right there.

Change

```
// This is a performance optimization of contains.
if (searchString.indexOf(stringInCollection, 0) > -1) {
```

[back] to

```
if (searchString.contains(stringInCollection)) {
```

If you're interested, the trie I tested with is here: http://ahocorasick.org/ and the code is quite simple.  The problem I saw is that is doesn't have a feature for early-out after finding the first match.  It parses the whole string and finds all matches.  It was faster than indexOf() for cases where there were no matches (830K/sec) but still slower than contains().

Apparently http://ahocorasick.org/ is gone.

Very similar code (possibly the same) can be found at https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick

Comment: The link is dead, unfortunately. Can you fix it please?

Comment: The performance gain heavily depends on the data. For example if the string is sufficiently long, then the speedup is proportional to the number of substrings (about 30) in the ideal world. However, the inner loop of e.g. Aho-Corasick algorithm is more complex than of `contains`, therefore can be a few times slower, but not nearly as slow as 30 times. It would be really interesting to benchmark the solutions for long strings to see the difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with this solution:

```
    final String[] searchList = searchCollection.toArray(new String[0]);
    Arrays.sort(searchList, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o1 == null || o1.isEmpty()) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o2 == null || o2.isEmpty()) {
                return -1;
            }
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    final int result = Arrays.binarySearch(searchList, searchString);
    return result >= 0 ? true : false;
```

Comment: This is assuming the list of strings is sorted, which isn't stated anywhere? If the list isn't sorted, it would make sense to sort it before passing it to this function so it only gets sorted once and not every time the function is called. Other than that I agree with this solution.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the problem in the question. It works only for exact matches of `searchString` and a string in the list, but the question asks about substrings.

Answer (score 1):

@Yrlec from your comment that the searchCollection can be thought of as constant with not much of modifications , you can sort the arraylist and cache it or you can implement custom List class which stores a reference to the sorted elements which are added to it.

The reason for this is if you have your searchCollection sorted then you can use compareTo method of String and reduce the number of iterations thus enhancing your method performance to an extent.

```
public static boolean containsAny(String searchString, List<String> searchCollectionSorted) {
    int size = searchCollectionSorted.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String stringInCollection = searchCollectionSorted.get(i);
        if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(stringInCollection)) {
            if (stringInCollection.compareToIgnoreCase(searchString) > 0) {
                if (searchString.startsWith(stringInCollection) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // No point of iterating if we reach here as the searchstring is greater and hence iterations are saved improving performance
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works only if `searchString` starts with any `stringInCollection`, but will not work if it contains `stringInCollection` in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HashSet data structure. But a hash set will not allow duplicates. For example, you cannot have the string "foo" twice in the HashSet.

On the plus side, the complexity should be O(1).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: This isn't related to the question

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet,HashSet or PrefixTree are quite good solutions. 
You should prefer PrefixTree if you 'll need to search whether a given prefix exists in the collection(complexity O(length(S)),otherwise use HashSet. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html